# Jquery append not working in IE9, but works in compatibility?

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-9

I have the following javascript code which appends a input element in a div. This works in firefox, chrome and IE9 compatibility mode, however it does not work in IE9.

```
function add(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".lbl").append("<div>Bild (400x400px)<br/><input type='file' name='upload[]' id='upload[]' onChange='add()' /><br/>Bild beskrivning:<br/><textarea name='imgdesc[]'></textarea></div>");
    });
}
window.load(add());
```

This is the html code where the appending is being done, it is located inside a form, inside a table td

```
<tr><td colspan="2">
    <div class='lbl'></div>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
    <input type="submit" name="newobject" value="Spara och granska">
</td></tr>
</table>
```

Any ideas on how to make this work in IE9?

Comment: May I ask why you are using jquery ready function when you are calling load with javascript functions? Why not use document ready on the outside to call add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(window).load(add());
});

function add() {
    $(".lbl").append("<div>Bild (400x400px)<br/><input type='file' name='upload[]' id='upload[]' onChange='add()' /><br/>Bild beskrivning:<br/><textarea name='imgdesc[]'></textarea></div>");
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sBVam/3/

It looks like IE9 doesn't support the load method as the error below shows up in the console

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'load' 
>   show, line 25 character 1

You can use jQuery's load method by making window a jQuery object.  Or you can use .onload method with the native window Dom Object.. ie.  `window.onload()`

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
window.onload = add();
```